# Does Serverless, Inc ever see my AWS credentials?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I would like to start using serverless-framework to manage lambda deploys at my company, but we handle PHI so security’s tight. Our compliance director and CTO had concerns about passing our AWS key and secret to another company.

When doing a `serverless deploy`, do AWS credentials ever actually pass through to Serverless, Inc?

If not, can someone point me to where in the code I can prove that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running serverless deploy isn't just one call, it's many.
AWS example (oversimplification):

- Check if deployment s3 bucket already exists
- Create an S3 bucket
- Upload packages to s3 bucket
- Call CloudFormation
- Check CloudFormation stack status
- Get info of created recourses (e.g. endpoint urls of created APIs)

And those calls can change dependent on what you are doing and what you have done before.

The point I'm trying to make is is that these calls which contain your credentials are not all located in one place and if you want to do a full code review of Serverless Framework and all it's dependencies, have fun with that.

But under the hood, we know that it's actually using the JavaScript aws-sdk (go check out the [package.json](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/package.json)), and we know what endpoints that uses {service}.{region}.amazonaws.com.

So to prove to your employers that nothing with your credentials is going anywhere except AWS you can just run a serverless deploy with wireshark running (other network packet analyzers are available). That way you can see anything that's not going to amazonaws.com

But wait, why are calls being made to serverless.com and serverlessteam.com when I run a deploy?

Well that's just tracking some stats and you can see what they track [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/slstats/). But if you are uber paranoid, this can be turned off with `serverless slstats --disable`.